# Convert wParam to virtual key code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am learning C# and .NET on my own. I am trying to learn how to subclass textbox according to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/815775) MSDN article. I have not used the exact subclass procedure from the article, but have tried something on my own.

The problem I have is converting properly `wParam` so I can compare it with virtual key code.

Below is the code for subclass procedure, and problematic parts are pointed out in comments:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BtnEdit
{
    public class SubclassEdit : TextBox
    {
        private const int WM_CHAR = 0x102;
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_CHAR:
                    {
                        // how to convert m.WParam ???
                        switch (m.WParam.ToInt32)
                        {
                            case 0x50: // this gives error
                                this.Text = "Pressed key P";
                                break;
                            default:
                                base.WndProc(ref m);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    //pass other messages to default procedure
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried `switch ( (Keys)m.WParam )` and then I was able to do something like `case Keys.A` and it worked. The problem with this approach is that in this case I can not test for small letter `a`. Also, things like `case Keys.Left` did not work either.

### **QUESTION:**

How should I modify my code so I can properly compare `wParam` with virtual key codes?

Comment: Just wanted to mention that there are other (some may argue simpler) ways of implementing custom keystroke logic. For example, instead of overriding `WndProc`, you could override `OnKeyDown` and use this code `base.OnKeyDown(e); if (e.KeyCode == Keys.P) { this.Text = "Pressed key P"; e.SuppressKeyPress = true; }`.

Comment: @gannaway: Thank you, I came to similar idea as well. I need to learn subclassing because it might get handy for other controls too. Thank you for your advice. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for WM_KEYDOWN as well, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

As for your error, you forgot the braces from .ToInt32()!
Check for 0x70 as well, (lower case p),

Comment: `You need to check for WM_KEYDOWN as well` I assume this was meant to help me with `Keys.Left` part of my post. Still, you haven't tried to help me with proper conversion of the `wParam` so I can see if letter `a` ( for example ) was pressed...

Comment: Updated my answer, to include the solution

Comment: I apologize for unaccepting, but I have one last problem: the code works when I press `SHIFT + P`, detecting capital P. How can I detect small p?

Comment: Updated, 0x70 is small p

Comment: Can you tell me where did you find this value? What about other UNICODE characters like `Ч` or some other Chinese symbols for example? I apologize for being a pain but I always tend to learn everything properly. MSDN documentation has no mention of this, that is why I ask. Best regards.

Comment: I just added 32 (0x20) to your upper case P which is how the Ascii table works. To check for unicode, simply find the unicode value.

Comment: I use this table all the time as a reference -> http://www.asciitable.com/ (look under the Hx (Hex) column to find the values mentioned in the question and answer)

Comment: I have found a way to use UNICODE symbols as well. For those with the same problem I will post my solution here: UNICODE symbol is given as U+some number. I just add prefix 0x before that number and everything works fine. Example for Cyrillic letter `ч` : U+0447 becomes 0x447 in the `case` statement. For UNICODE reference I used [this](http://unicode-table.com/en/#0447) site. Thanks again for helping me out. Best regards until next time.